# Angular mat cards with left and right arrow slider

Tags: html, angular, slider, mat-card

I want only three of my mat cards to appear on the screen and there should be a left arrow and right arrow. When we click on right arrow the cards should move and we should be able to see the next cards till the end, same with the left arrow for previous cards.
[image: how I want]

This is how I want it.But the first arrow should be near to the card.
Is there any default module in angular I can use for this? If not, what code I need to write in both html and ts for this?